# RSpec before in a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
module MyHelper
  before (:each) do
    allow(Class).to receive(:method).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

Then in my tests I could do something like:

```
RSpec.describe 'My cool test' do
  include MyHelper
  it 'Tests a Class Method' do
    expect { Class.method }.to eq true
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** This produces the following error:

```
undefined method `before' for MyHelper:Module (NoMethodError)
```

---

Essentially I have a case where many tests do different things, but a common model across off of them reacts on an after_commit which ends up always calling a method which talks to an API. I dont want to GLOBALLY allow `Class` to receive `:method` as, sometimes, I need to define it myself for special cases... but I'd like to not have to repeat my allow/receive/and_return and instead wrap it in a common helper...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a [hook that is triggered via metadata](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/hooks/filters), for example `:type => :api`:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before(:each, :type => :api) do
    allow(Class).to receive(:method).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

And in your spec:

```
RSpec.describe 'My cool test', :type => :api do
  it 'Tests a Class Method' do
    expect { Class.method }.to eq true
  end
end
```

You can also pass `:type => :api` to individual `it` blocks.

Comment: perfect solution! :)

Comment: This nails it! Thanks @Stefan :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to do things like you want with feature called [shared_context](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context)

You could create the shared file with code like this

**shared_file.rb**

```
shared_context "stubbing :method on Class" do
  before { allow(Class).to receive(:method).and_return(true) }
end
```

Then you could include that context in the files you needed in the blocks you wanted like so

**your_spec_file.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shared_file'

RSpec.describe 'My cool test' do
  include_context "stubbing :method on Class"
  it 'Tests a Class Method' do
    expect { Class.method }.to eq true
  end
end
```

And it will be more naturally for RSpec than your included/extended module helpers. It would be "RSpec way" let's say.

Comment: Is this only available in rspec 3.6+?

Comment: I think I'm on an old version of rspec; I get this error: `undefined method `shared_context_metadata_behavior=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x007ffbd7e74570> (NoMethodError)` -- Other than that, this is probably the correct aswer for latest rspec...

Comment: Not sure about that. I believe I was using it in rspec 3.0. Anyway you can follow the link in my answer, select your rspec version there and find out if that feature is supported by your version

Answer (score 0):

You could separate that code into shared_context and include it into example groups (not examples) like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'My cool test' do
  shared_context 'class stub' do
    before (:each) do
      allow(Class).to receive(:method).and_return(true)
    end
  end

  describe "here I am using it" do
    include_context 'class stub'

    it 'Tests a Class Method' do
      expect { Class.method }.to eq true
    end
  end

  describe "here I am not" do
    it 'Tests a Class Method' do
      expect { Class.method }.not_to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Shared context can contain `let`, helper functions & everything you need except examples.
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context